# Recommended way to divide QUnit module and QUnit Test

Tags: javascript, sapui5, qunit

When I code QUnit test, a question strikes me. What is the best way to organize QUnit module and QUnit test(assertion tests)? And how to define the relationship between QUnit module and the to-be-test function.

In practice, I usually relate one function to one atomic module, and one QUnit module is related to several atomic assertion tests. The codes are as follows. But is it always effective and practical in engineering project? And if there is a principle to divide QUnit module and QUnit tests?

I am appreciated for your kind answer!

```
        //function 1 
        numberUnit: function (sValue) {
            if (!sValue) {
                return "";
            }
            return parseFloat(sValue).toFixed(2);
        },
        //function 2
        priceState: function(iPrice){
            if(iPrice < 50) {
                return "Success";
            }else if(iPrice >= 50 && iPrice < 250){
                return "None";
            }else if(iPrice >=250 && iPrice <2000){
                return "Warning";
            }else {
                return "Error";
            }
        }

    //module 1, related to function 1
    QUnit.module("Number unit");
    function numberUnitValueTestCase(assert, sValue, fExpectedNumber) {
        // Act
        var fNumber = formatter.numberUnit(sValue);

        // Assert
        assert.strictEqual(fNumber, fExpectedNumber, "The rounding was correct");
    }
    QUnit.test("Should round down a 3 digit number", function (assert) {
        numberUnitValueTestCase.call(this, assert, "3.123", "3.12");
    });
    QUnit.test("Should round up a 3 digit number", function (assert) {
        numberUnitValueTestCase.call(this, assert, "3.128", "3.13");
    });
    QUnit.test("Should round a negative number", function (assert) {
        numberUnitValueTestCase.call(this, assert, "-3", "-3.00");
    });
    QUnit.test("Should round an empty string", function (assert) {
        numberUnitValueTestCase.call(this, assert, "", "");
    });
    QUnit.test("Should round a zero", function (assert) {
        numberUnitValueTestCase.call(this, assert, "0", "0.00");
    });

    //module 2, related to function 2
    QUnit.module("Price State");
    //priceStateTestCase, reduce codes repeatance
    function priceStateTestCase(oOptions){
        //act
        var sState = formatter.priceState(oOptions.price);
        //assert
        oOptions.assert.strictEqual(sState,oOptions.expected, "The price state was correct!");
    }
    QUnit.test("Should format the products with a price lower than 50 to Success",function(assert){
        priceStateTestCase.call(this,{
            assert: assert,
            price: 42,
            expected: "Success"
        }); 
    });
    QUnit.test("Should format the products with a price of 50 to Normal",function(assert){
        priceStateTestCase.call(this,{
            assert: assert,
            price: 50,
            expected: "None"
        });
    });
    QUnit.test("Should format the products with a price between 50 and 250 to Normal",function(assert){
        priceStateTestCase.call(this,{
            assert: assert,
            price: 134,
            expected: "None"
        });
    });
```